# How to unlink an AppleID / iCloud Account from an iPhone that's been used 3 times?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id

I work at a place where they re-issue iPhones to various employees.  One of these iPhones has been re-issued at least 3 times.  Which means that there are at least 3 Apple ID/iCloud accounts that have been associated with this iPhone.

The procedure was to [wipe the phone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201441) ( Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content) and then create a new Apple ID / iCloud account for the new user using the phone.

However...today we got a message that said `Can’t Create AppleID` `This device is no longer eligible for creating a free iCloud account`, and I believe that is because three people had accounts associated with it before.

I've tried loggging into their iCloud accounts on http://apple.com/find and the device is not listed there as it is [preportedly supposed to be](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201441) so I can unlink it.

Comment: did your company use the company-program of Apple when buying the iPhones?

Comment: @Gabkano Ya got me...I didn't buy them...which phone companies have that?

Comment: @Gabkano Are you referring to this? http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/

Comment: Hmm maybe this is how Apple stops Businesses from not participating in their VPP program; would have been nice if they told us that upfront.

Comment: @Gabkano Or are you talking about DEP: https://www.apple.com/business/dep/

Comment: no the details aren't important,but if you ever got in contact with Apple to buy phones for a company( as I don't think someone from your company went to the AppleStore and bought 100 iPhones or so) you probably got information about a person you can get in touch if you got problems with devices, especially in those cases.

Comment: We don't really have an Apple Store here...we have two companies at the mall that sell them.

Comment: or that, but you know what I mean

Comment: I haven't done this so I'm not 100% positive, but I think you can goto http://appleid.apple.com and use the create Apple ID button there, then use that appleid as an existing when setting the phone up.

Comment: @Tyson That was it, thank you.  Add it as the answer if you like.